# Replacing a character in all files names of a directory

Tags: find, command, xargs, replace

*This is homework!*

I'm trying to replace all spaces in file names with an underscore in the `yay` directory. It asks me to use the commands xargs and sh without using $(command). I tried using conducts of commands, but it keeps displaying this message:

```
sh: 1: Bad substitution
```

Could someone explain why this message keeps popping up?

Here's are the commands I tired using:

```
find yay -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} sh -c 'newname="${1// /_}"; mv "$1" "$newname"' sh
```

AND

```
find yay -type f -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "${1// /_}"' _ {} \;
```

Comment: `sh` is only required to be POSIX compliant, and `${parameter//pattern/replacement}` isn't one of the [POSIX parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) capabilities - it is supported in shells such as `ksh`, `bash`, and `zsh`

Answer (score 0):

The `sh` shell does not understand the `/` substitution. (It does understand `%` and and `#`, though.) You need a shell such as `bash` for this:

```
find yay -type f -exec bash -c 'mv -- "$1" "${1// /_}"' _ {} \;
```

You can more efficiently write this by reducing the number of invocations of the shell (currently one per file), and only renaming a file if the destination does not already exist:

```
find yay -type f -name '* *' -exec bash -c 'for f in "$@"; do g=${f// /_}; [ ! -e "$g" ] && mv -f -- "$f" "$g"; done' _ {} +
```

While testing, prefix `mv` with `echo` and you'll get a printout of (an approximation to) what would be executed without any action really being taken.